# Model Filtering Joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model

This is my posting model. Posts have many user_ids through postings. I'd like to return the Posts that have user_id 2 and 3. So posts with ID 7 and 8.

Ideally my code would look something like this... but it doesn't work

Post.joins(:postings).where("postings.user_id = ?", [2,3])

```
id  | post_id | user_id | created_at                | updated_at                |
+---+---------+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1 | 7       | 1      | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 |
| 2 | 7       | 2      | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 |
| 3 | 7       | 3      | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 | 2013-09-07 16:03:50 -0400 |
| 4 | 8       | 2      | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 |
| 5 | 8       | 3      | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 |
| 6 | 8       | 6      | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 | 2013-09-07 22:17:49 -0400 |
| 7 | 12      | 3      | 2013-09-14 12:49:56 -0400 | 2013-09-14 12:49:56 -0400 |
```

**ADDED COMMENTS**

- I am using Rails
- I'd like to be able to keep the [2,3] dynamic so there can be 10 entries in the array or 2
- the Post table does not have a user_id column. The Posting model has a user_id column and the User table has a id column. The relationship between the two has been setup using a has_many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to solve these problems using aggregation with logic in the `having` clause, because this is the most flexible approach to these types of questions:

```
select post_id
from postings
group by post_id
having sum(case when user_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when user_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of records that match each user id.

EDIT:

Depending on the indexes that you have on the tables, the following might actually perform better for this particular problem:

```
select p2.user_id
from postings p2 join
     postings p3
     on p2.post_id = p3.post_id and
        p2.user_id = 2 and
        p3.user_id = 3;
```

EDIT II:

For a dynamic list, you could do:

```
select post_id
from postings
where user_id in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
group by post_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 5;
```

Comment: I used your later function without the "having count(distinct user_id = 5)" It does the same as Posting.where(:user_id => [2,3]) which returns 7,8,12.. this is incorrect. I would only like to see those that have user_id 2 as well as 3, not those that have 2 or 3.

Comment: @ebbflowgo . . . That is why you need the `having count(distinct) = # of elements`.

Comment: beautiful, thank you! I now understand why you put a count of 5.